# Working with heavy/time-consuming functions in react (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rsa, background-task

Good evening, I have a React project where when the user opens a page, the application starts creating a 2048 RSA key pair. How do I make sure that the page doesn't "crash", that is, it stays in the background and when the key is created I inform the user that everything is ready.

```
            const navigate = useNavigate();
            const [keyStatus, setKeyStatus] = useState('Em processamento... (É normal que a pagina parece ter crashado! Por favor espere!)');
            const [pubKey, setPubKey] = useState('');
            const [privKey, setPrivKey] = useState('');
            const [genState, setGenState] = useState(0);
            function exitModal(){
                modal.setModal(true);
            }
            async function downloadPrivKey() {
                if(genState === 1){
                    await api.post('/savePublicKey', {
                        publicKey: pubKey
                    }).then(function(response){
                        fileDownload(privKey, 'private.key', 'text/plain');
                        setGenState(2);
                    }).catch(function (){
                        navigate('/', { replace: true });
                    });
                }
            }
useEffect(() => {
    async function startGenerationKeys() {
        const keysWorker = new Worker();
        keysWorker.postMessage("start");
        keysWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
            setPrivKey(e.data.privKey);
            setPubKey(e.data.pubKey);
            setKeyStatus('Pronta para download!');
            setGenState(1);
        };
    }
    startGenerationKeys();
}, []);
         return (
                <Container>
                    <PageTitle>Criação das chaves</PageTitle>
                    <InstructionText>Você irá precisar da sua chave privada para poder usar a plataforma!</InstructionText>
                    <AlertText>Em caso de perda da sua chave não será possivel recuperar as suas passwords pessoais!</AlertText>
                    <AlertText>Não se esqueça de transferir a sua chave!</AlertText>
                    <AlertText>Não feche este separador durante a criação das chaves!</AlertText>
                    <InstructionText>Estado das chaves: {keyStatus}</InstructionText>
                    <BtnsZone>
                        <BtnBox isClicable={genState !== 0 ? true : false} onClick={downloadPrivKey}>
                            <FaDownload size={15} color="#FFF" />
                            <BtnText>Descarregar chave privada</BtnText>
                        </BtnBox>
                        <BtnBox isClicable={genState === 2 ? true : false}>
                            <MdNextWeek size={20} color="#FFF" />
                            <BtnText>Prosseguir para a plataforma</BtnText>
                        </BtnBox>
                    </BtnsZone>
                    <BtnBox isClicable={true} isAlone={true} onClick={exitModal}>
                        <ImExit color="#FFF" size={22} />
                        <BtnText>Terminar sessão</BtnText>
                    </BtnBox>
                </Container>
            );
```

WebWorker:

```
        import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';

    export default onmessage = function() {
        const keysPair = new NodeRSA({ b: 4096 });
        const pubKey = keysPair.exportKey('public').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        const privKey = keysPair.exportKey('private');
        postMessage({
            pubKey,
            privKey
        });
    }
```

Comment: what does your jsx for this component look like?

Comment: Ok, I add my jsx component to the question.

Comment: Have you looked into web workers?

Comment: With WebWorker the page seems to crash, including the warning of "Page unanswered" from Google Chrome.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the worker correctly. You'll need to show where `Worker` comes from – if that's the usual `Worker()` constructor, you'd need to pass it the worker code URL.

Comment: Also, have you considered [`Crypto.subtle.generateKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey)?

Comment: Shouldn't the web worker stuff be asked in a new question? This feels like the question is getting less focused.

Answer (score 0):

I am not talking about interacting with the page. I am saying check for a piece of state inside your component and doing something based on it. So for example.

under useEffect before the return

```
if(keyStatus !== "Pronta para download!") return <div>Loading..</div>
```

Set it to wait for the key to be ready to download?

**Edit**

I think this will work once you get the web worker stuff figured out. Basically you just have the screen show loading until the state updates to say that the key is ready to download. You can add in some ui spinner to make the screen show movement. So that the end user knows that something is happening and the site didn't crash.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the problem lies in the fact that the browser blocks (does not let you interact with the page) when processing the creation of the key pair. Sometime the user is redirected to root /

Comment: In this case what is inside the IF is loaded but even so with a webWorker the page seems to crash, including the warning of "Page unanswered" from Google Chrome.